# SeekBar prog not running

Tags: android, android-emulator

A Simple SeekBar Program is not running.I'm not sure what i'm missing.
The java file is given as

`package com.tree;`

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class tree extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SeekBar sb=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sb);
        final TextView tv=new TextView(this);
        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            tv.setText(progress);
        }
    });
    }
```

}

and the layout xml file is given as

Any help would be appreciated.The error thrown is "that the Program has stopped unexpectedly".

Comment: Please try to fix it up so the code can be viewed, and provide the layout xml and android manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `tv.setText(progress);`.
setText(int) expects a resource identifier, not an integer.
Instead use `tv.setText(Integer.toString(progress));` to convert to a string first.